# I need to pull all paragraphs from any website

Tags: html, html-parsing

I need to take any random website and pull all chunks of text from the website.

I am calling this "paragraph disambiguation" (see "sentence disambiguation" in Wikipedia).

I don't care if these chunks themselves contain other HTML like  or  as I can get rid of these after I extract the paragraphs text.

I also need to distinguish between the paragraphs as in, this is paragraph 1 and this is paragraph 2 and so on.

I am aware that most paragraphs would typically be contained in a

tag. But this is not always the case. Text can also be contained in the following:

```
<div>
<span>
<td>
<li>
```

Is there any other HTML elements that might contain a block of text?

Is there any other methodology of extracting text blocks from a random webpage, like looking for "white words" and then finding their boundaries?

Thanks in advance

Jeff

Comment: What exactly it your question? How to do it? Or just if there are other text elements?

Answer (score 0):

Nearly all HTML elements may include texts:

- p
- dt
- dd
- td
- th

And many more I can't recall at the moment. Take a look at the **[Complete list of HTML tags](http://www.quackit.com/html/tags/)** and see which is suitable to contain text, and which is not.

Comment: Ok, well, if I gave you a random web page and told you to take out all the readable text off of it, how would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use Python's Beautiful Soup and call .get_text() on the body element.  This will give you all the text in the page.

From [Documentation on get_text()](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text):

```
>>> markup = '<a href="http://example.com/">\nI linked to <i>example.com</i>\n</a>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(markup)
>>> soup.get_text()
u'\nI linked to example.com\n'
```